# Execute web service on background every

Tags: android, android-background, android-webservice

I need to execute web service every Hour in the background

Every hour, will check if Internet is available then execute a web service and update data.

How can I do this?

My background service

```
public class MyService extends Service {

   String tag="TestService";
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
       Log.i(tag, "Service created...");
   }

   @Override
   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {      
       super.onStart(intent, startId);  
       if(isInternet)
       {
           AsyTask web= new AsyTask();
           web.execute();
       }
       Log.i(tag, "Service started...");
   }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;

   }
```

Comment: What have you tried? show your code.
In short, just use `AlarmManager` that is called every hour

Comment: you have to use service and set timer in onStart method of service and call webservice in that

Comment: I am making service but dont know how i can execute every hour

Comment: i have add code sample below,please try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea would be to use the AlarmManager to start a background service every hour.

Setup Alarm Manager to start a background service every 60 minutes. This can be done in any of the activities.

```
    startServiceIntent = new Intent(context,
            WebService.class);
    startWebServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            startServiceIntent, 0);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            System.currentTimeMillis(), 60*1000*60,
            startWebServicePendingIntent);
```

Create a class `WebService` which extends `Service` then add the method to sync data with the server inside the `onStartCommand()` method of the Service. Also, do not forget to declare the service in the manifest.

Edit 1 :

```
public class WebService extends Service {

   String tag="TestService";
   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Service created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
       Log.i(tag, "Service created...");
   }

   @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       super.onStart(intent, startId);  
       if(isInternet)
       {
           AsyTask web= new AsyTask();
           web.execute();
       }
       Log.i(tag, "Service started...");
   }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       Toast.makeText(this, "Service destroyed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;

   }
```

Comment: How can use this in service

Comment: You'll add this code inside the MainActivity of your application so that whenever the app is started, Alarm manager sets this repeating alarm.

Comment: then how i connected this code through service class

Comment: You are connecting it through the PendingIntent (startWebServicePendingIntent above) which uses the Intent(startServiceIntent) which starts the service(WebService.class)

Comment: I am new in android so i am not understanding please provide same code or edit my service class

Comment: Add the code that I've mentioned in my answer to the onCreate Method of your main activity. Rename MyService to WebService. Also, check Edit 1 of my answer.

Comment: If MainActivity destroyed by system(when it is in the background for long time) then what will happen? Is it call or not?

Answer (score 0):

add you code of calling webservice inside run method of timer task just like below

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
   if(isInternet)
   {
       AsyTask web= new AsyTask();
       web.execute();
   }
   Log.i(tag, "Service started...");
}
}, 0, 3600000);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but AlarmManger is best or Timer ?

Comment: i have used this, and it is working fine. so you can use this.

Comment: i think AlaramMAnger is a long way, if we can do same thing easly with timer, so we should use this.